# ex48 Learn Python the hard way

Tags: python, nosetests

```
direction = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right', 'back']
verbs     = ['go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat']
stop      = ['the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it']
nouns     = ['door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet']
numbers   = [i for i in range(10)]


class lexicon(object):

    def scan(self, sentence):
        self.sentence = sentence
        self.words    = sentence.split()
        for word in self.words:
            if word is direction:
                word = ('direction','%s' % word)

            return word
```

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html is what I am working on, I don't know why my program doesn't pass the test. When I run nosetests I get this error.

```
ERROR: tests.ex48_tests.test_directions
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tplaw/Public/projects/installs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/tplaw/Public/projects/ex48/tests/ex48_tests.py", line 6, in test_directions
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
TypeError: unbound method scan() must be called with lexicon instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.005s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

and I only put the first aprt of the test in my tests directory. It is this:

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex48 import lexicon

def test_directions():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
    result = lexicon.scan("north south east")
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                          ('direction', 'south'),
                          ('direction', 'east')])
```

Comment: `lexicon` is a (badly named; use a capital at the start) class, not an instance. You're trying to call an instance method without first constructing an instance.

Comment: I instantiated it, and ran nosetests again and I get an AssertionError:

Comment: line 6, in test_directions
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
AssertionError: 'north' != [('direction', 'north')]

Comment: You have an `is` that was probably meant to be `in`. Also an indentation problem. And a bad use of the same name for 2 things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lexicon.scan
```

is an *instance* method, not a *class* or *static* method. You have to construct a `lexicon`, then call `scan` on that.

```
lex = lexicon() # This will create an instance of the lexicon class
lex.scan() # This will invoke the instance method of the instantiated class
```

Comment: ok, I get that now. In the previous exercise the test created instances so I didn't need to put it in the module. But now I have a different error, and I don't know how to do it. I'm supposed to form a new sentence out of tuples in order to pass the test. I don't know how to do that. It also seems like my code is completely skipping the "if word is direction:" part and I've never seen that syntax so I don't even think it's right, but I want to check if it is in the list and then make it a tuple with the name of the list as the first part of the tuple and the word as the second part.

Answer (score 0):

Always so a capital letter in the beginning of a class name. And later instantiate your class to invoke it's instance methods.

```
class Lexicon(object):
    def scan(self, sentence):
        self.sentence = sentence
        self.words    = sentence.split()
        for word in self.words:
            if word in direction: # probably should be in and not is
                word = ('direction','%s' % word)

            return word

## in your test
def test_directions():
    lexicon_instance = Lexicon()
    assert_equal(lexicon_instance.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
    result = lexicon_instance.scan("north south east")
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                      ('direction', 'south'),
                      ('direction', 'east')])
```